# Anybody have installed xcode 14 on opencore patched macbook?

Tags: xcode, opencore

I have an old MacBook(late 2013) and apple dropped support for monetary, but there is this [opencore](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/START.html#how-do-i-get-started) patch that allows installation monetary on old mac, I wonder if anybody installed Xcode 14 on it and if it is working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've installed Ventura (13.2) on a Mid 2014 MacBook Pro (last supported MacOS: Big Sur 11.6.6).
Xcode 14.2 is working as expected: i'm coding, debugging and releasing apps.
At the moment the only problem is that iOS 16 emulators are showing a black screen, but iOS 15 emulators are working properly.

It seems to be a problem related with the unsupported graphic card.
Some people are experiencing problems also on viewing storyboard files (not me).

Maybe Monterey is more compatible but I've not tried it yet

https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/z5xw07/ios_simulator_black_screen_after_upgrading_to/

https://www.olarila.com/topic/27887-ios-simulator-xcode-134-only-show-black-screen/

Comment: I managed to install Monterey and Xcode 14.2 and it works fine up to now, but there is a problem with the Intel graphic card. The colors are dull and the videos are muddy.
Besides that, never restore the whole system with the Migration Assistant. I ended up in infinite loops of the restart. Restore it folder base.

Comment: I run the update without resetting the mac https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/POST-INSTALL.html#booting-without-usb-drive
Did you run the "Post Install Root Patch" from the OpenCore-Pacher menu?
I had some screen resolution related problem before doing this

Comment: yes, I did Root Patch, I even managed to install Xcode, but the simulator flickers badly, and I think it is something related to Automatic graphics switching, the MacBook has an Intel and NVIDIA Gforce graphic card,  because whenever I disable it from the battery settings, it uses only the Intel one and now the simulator goes completely black. I think the NVIDIA card driver is not supported any more in Monetery. No workaround yet.

Comment: Try installing and using older simulators, I know in this way you cant't test new devices support but at least you can test your app. For me is working

Comment: which version worked for you? I tried iOS 15.5 with no hope!

Comment: I tried 15.5 and it is working nicely

Comment: @mehdi my workaround was selecting in simulator's menu:  File -> GPU Selection -> Prefer Integrated GPU then relaunch the simulator